# Issue Removing Anaconda from MacOS

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I downloaded Anaconda Navigator to my Mac (macOS Sierra). I am trying to cleanly uninstall Anaconda so that there is no trace of it and so python reverts to how it was out-of-the-box.

I have followed the instructions about Anaconda-Clean at this site: https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#uninstall-anaconda

However, when I type the command `python` from the terminal, I still see Anaconda's presence:

`Ryans-MacBook-Pro:~ ryan$ python
Python 3.5.2 |Anaconda 4.2.0 (x86_64)| (default, Jul  2 2016, 17:52:12) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 4.2 (clang-425.0.28)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`

What do I do to clean this up?

Thanks,
Ryan

Comment: In my case, `anaconda-clean` left the whole `anaconda` folder. And as in your case `python` still run anaconda python. After restarting terminal, everything got back to normal

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using the simple remove instructions on the page you linked to:
https://docs.continuum.io/anaconda/install#uninstall-anaconda

First do `which python` to see where the old conda python is residing.

> OS X: Open the Terminal.app or iTerm2 terminal application and remove your entire Anaconda directory, which will have a name such as “anaconda2” or “anaconda3”, by entering the following command: rm -rf ~/anaconda3

I don't know why the anaconda-clean did not work for you.

Comment: Alex - I did the 'simple remove' already to no avail. Per your suggestion about 'which python' - the response is "//anaconda/bin/conda". Therefore, I should use the command 'rm -rf ~/anaconda' right? I have tried this as well.

Comment: I have never seen that before! `//anaconda/bin/conda` is the same as `/anaconda/bin/conda` (the double slash is identical to single slash). That indicates it's in the root directory, not in `~` which is your home directory. I would do `rm -rf /anaconda` if that is what you are seeing. But be very careful. Do not do `rm -rf /` ! That would be catastrophic.

Comment: haha. And I'm a brand new Mac user, so a little out of my comfort zone.

Comment: Let me know if that does not fix it for you. And please upvote or accept answer if it worked!

Comment: Alex - Just tried your suggestion and got the following error:  `rm: /anaconda: Permission denied`

Comment: Try `sudo rm -rf /anaconda`. That should give elevated privileges for the command. This is just unix filesystem stuff, which OS X has because it has a bsd unix system.

Comment: Boom. Thanks, Alex. That did it. Much obliged.
`Ryans-MacBook-Pro:babynames ryan$ python
Python 2.7.10 (default, Jul 30 2016, 19:40:32) 
[GCC 4.2.1 Compatible Apple LLVM 8.0.0 (clang-800.0.34)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.`.  Also...the `which conda` trick was very helpful.

Answer (score 1):

for me anaconda3 was located at /opt/anaconda3 so i did `rm -rf /opt/anconda3`